# How to use ng-If/*ng-If inside of angular materials table <td>

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to implement ng-If inside of a table `<td>` in order to achieve displaying Active/Deactivated and Locked, status for an account based on the screenshot below. While my angular code compiled, As can be seen in the screenshot, 2 accounts (in red) are locked and status should display Locked. However the two accounts below the ones in red are not locked, thus the `<td>` element for locked should not show at all, only the `<td>` for Active status.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" ng-if="row.isLocked === true" [ngClass]="{ 'Locked':row.isLocked == true}"> Locked equals {{row.isLocked}} Active equals {{row.isActive}} </td>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" ng-if="row.isActive === true" [ngClass]="{ 'Active':row.isActive == true}"> Locked equals {{row.isLocked}} Active equals {{row.isActive}}</td>
```

[image]

Comment: isn't it *ngIf? or [ngIf].

Comment: @rdr20 you can't do `*ngIf` because of the `*matCellDef`, otherwise it will bomb. [ngIf] seems to result in some odd behavior in which only the first row displays and its only first and last name displaying. All other column data no longer renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Locked equals {{row.isLocked}} Active equals {{row.isActive}}
```

returns `Locked equals 0 Active equals true` or `Locked equals 1 Active equals false`.
Since, `isLocked` is returning value 0 or 1, the property isn't bolean.
So, you need to check the value of `isLocked` with 0 or 1; or you can change the property type to boolean.

**First way (not changing isLocked property type)**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <p *ngIf="row.isLocked === 1">Content when isLocked is 1</p>
    <p *ngIf="row.isActive">Content when isActive is true</p>
</td>
```

**Second way (changing isLocked property type to boolean)**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <p *ngIf="row.isLocked">Content when isLocked is true</p>
    <p *ngIf="row.isActive">Content when isActive is true</p>
</td>
```

Just follow the format and apply your customizations.